# Friends, should we not adopt a rubric for Q&A?

Tags: discussion

Paul Ross in a response suggested that a rubric might be in order.

[Friends, what exactly is the difference between 'being a philosopher' and 'being a philosophy SME'?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/friends-what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-being-a-philosopher-and-being/5212#5212)

He suggested as guidance:

https://www.ed.ac.uk/ppls/philosophy/current/undergraduate/assessment/marking-guidelines

The following is offered as a focal point for a series of explications to be ADDED TO THE FAQ after building and evaluating a consensus:

1. Isn't it incumbent upon editors of Q&A philosophy to have a formal explication on what constitutes a good question and a good answer that is neither simple fact nor opinion?
2. Are the guidelines in the FAQ really so clear as to defuse any confusion?
3. Do we have adequate explanations and examples of each of the following sorts of questions?

**Clarity**
Is the writing clear and free of contradiction?
Are the grammar and spelling correct in accordance with convention?
Is the language used appropriately?

**Structure**
Is a clear question or answer stated?
Is a balanced NPOV argument, or arguments, offered as an answer?
Is the body clearly organized?

**Understanding**
Is a sound understanding of relevant issues demonstrated?
Is the exposition of others’ views accurate?
Are technical terms adequately used or defined?

**Neutral Point of View**
To what extent does the question or answer use NPOV?
How many citations are present?
What is the nature of the citations?

Comment: One should definitely discuss this further, even if a conclusion is not drawn

Comment: @JuliusH. Absolutely, but this form of social organization does not facilitate the sort of cohesion necessary for a strong consensus. This form of organization is like a libertarian bazaar wherein one can find some rather talented individuals, but is also awash in a sea of, charitably, mediocrity.