# Should there be a "reopen/undelete suggestions" thread on meta?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-answers, deleted-questions

There's a [thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today) - actually, series of threads - on math.stackexchange for people to nominate questions/answers for reponening/undeletion as appropriate. I think the same type of thread would be appropriate here, but I'm hesitant to create it since my opinion on its value may not be shared by the community here.

If there is reasonable consensus that such a thread would be a good thing, I'll go ahead and start one (or someone else can of course).

Comment: Added answers for voting. Feel free to edit them if they seem biased. I think it is a good idea.

Comment: Also, additional arguments pro/con may be added

Comment: We should also learn in advance from mathSE of running such a thread and read posts like: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17262/the-reopen-request-thread-and-closures-on-meta?rq=1, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19045/whether-when-and-why-to-have-a-new-reopen-and-undelete-request-thread?rq=1, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21411/should-i-wait-before-posting-in-requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes?rq=1.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, we should have such threads

Sometimes good posts (questions and answers alike) are forgotten and never appear in the review queue after closure or deletion (there needs to be at least one vote for reopening/undeletion for that). And even if it is in the review queue, this queue in particular rarely gets the attention it deserves so that we rarely have the five votes needed either way. Thus, such a meta thread is a good way to raise attention and discuss borderline cases. And it keeps meta tidy.

Comment: Yes, and we should aspire to have more of this fashion?

Comment: @YechiamWeiss Any example of what that could be?

Comment: I'm not around many SEs so I can't think of any example such as this one; perhaps others may help. But I think (meta?) posts as "community wiki" are a very good way of dealing with frequently-repeated topics. A good "philosophy internet sources wiki post", "acceptable logic questions wiki post", perhaps even stuff like "short overview of idealism wiki post". It's not exactly the same kind of posts, but the same idea applies: having a centralized place for frequently-discussed topics. Obviously the idea needs more work, as in who maintains these posts, who writes them (who revises if needed?).

Comment: And here's a thread that is indeed of the same type: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24972/the-duplicate-thread?

Comment: Accidently stumbled across a question of the kind I wrote about: [a community wiki on resources for contemporary philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/256/where-and-how-can-i-get-started-in-contemporary-philosophy). I think those kind of posts should be pinned in the front page (we had such a discussion a while back if you recall).

Answer (score 0):

### No, we should not have such a thread

Basically, closed questions get deleted automatically *if they are abandoned by the OP*. Direct deletion applies solely to serious violation of our terms of service. And since every OP is free to open an individual thread for their closed question or deleted post and cases can be discussed more pointedly there, we do not need such a thread.

Answer (score 0):

### YES, task management threads such as close and reopen help to simplify and encourage shared ownership of moderation

I rise to support this motion. One of my biggest concerns is that there is not enough incentive to spend time on MetaSE to learn how to do the business of the community. After spending a year on and off, I feel I am just starting to understand how the community functions in practice (as opposed to claims). Wikipedia makes excellent use of certain strategies such as bots, lists, FAQs, and portals. There have been repeated concerns expressed about excessive and mistaken closure, and by having a thread to make manifest what is on the agenda for opening and closing, I believe that there will be more activity.

See [Friends, how could a question about an idea with its own article in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy be closed as off-topic?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5185/friends-how-could-a-question-about-an-idea-with-its-own-article-in-the-stanford)