Can communal moderation (closing, downvoting) in principle support the fair rights of the minority?
Democracy vs tyranny of the majority - is a well-known fact. https://blog.oup.com/2022/01/majority-rule-is-not-democracy/
Even with dedicated editorial staff in scientific journals, there is always a struggle in picking right vs wrong, true vs false.
Then how could a simple reliance on a majority vote achieve a fair result?
In my understanding, the majority has to vote for moderators, and moderators will decide which questions have to be closed. That way, you would have more responsibility and accountability in this process.

My meta question refers your question where as I remember, you had accepted my answer. Am I misremembering? Or did the tick disappear of its own?

I can see reference to "Can communal moderation ..." under the 'Linked' section and your answer is still "Accepted".

For clarity: Does this question imply there any actual minority here that is harmed by the current state of affairs, or is this a purely theoretical question without significant evidence of trouble in practice?

As you may have seen, I am no fan of democracy but here I think you are misdiagnosing the issue: it is not democracy that is malfunctioning here. On the contrary it is the fact that some processes are escaping democratic purview that should be subject to up/down-vote.
In particular, comments and VTCs.

Negative comments (ie comments that dont add value) have no recourse other than flagging, so people escape by putting a pointless/snide/useless/incendiary etc etc in comments that would get downvoted in answers (questions)

VTCs are used as a costless sneaky way for

I dont like this philosophy
I dont like this methodology/approach/paradigm
I dont like this questioner/answerer



If VTCs and comments were brought under the democratic purview all this would stop or at least significantly reduce.
Your Suggestion
Moderators on SE are not meant to be like traditional editors, reviewers etc, they are the last resort glue to fill the cracks that somehow escaped the default community processes.
As I reminded at the top, I am no democracy fan but replacing the democratic process by preassigned editors/reviewers opens a different can of worms (or boa constrictors?):

who will certify the reviewer?
who will certify the certifier?
etc

This is an international forum. International fora quickly become like UN — massive sources of fine words, sinks of money and overseers of inaction.  In the circumstances, the democratic process is as good as you will get. It is the other leaks in the plumbing that need to be plugged.

You cannot create a perfect system. But you can always improve on an existing one. It reminds me of American movies: ignorance thrives, intelligence struggle. But I still don't understand why people are so eager to click "Close" and so reluctant to click "Reopen".

Ppl are using VTC as costless downvote. See https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5191/37256

In theory, "Reopen" could compensate for "Close", but it definitely does not (in philosophy meta). "Close" - act of aggression (more popular). "Reopen" - act of thoughtfulness (much more rare).

I only downvote or vote to close if I think something is actually damaging to the site. I have often voted to reopen if a question was reworked, to give it another hearing.

You are the best, but what about a couple of disgruntled individuals that almost automatically click on "Close" and never leave a note?

@TheMatrixEquation-balance I've used your comment above here. Hope that's ok. Even better if you can add to the discussion

The StackExchange approach to moderation includes:

community/user voting (both for score, and for closure/reopening)
moderator voting (which is often determinative)
moderator responses to flags (resulting in content deletion, moving material to chat, etc.)
other moderator actions (account suspensions, deletions, locks, etc.)

This moderation system is not intended to account for any "rights" of a minority. It also takes far from a majority of users to get something done. Sometimes, one user is enough, as for some automatically handled flags. A single gold-tag-badge user can close a question within that tag as a duplicate. And in general, users can close questions without the involvement of moderators.
You can read more at the help page and in StackExchange's "Theory of Moderation," which intentionally leaves most moderation in the hands of the community.

"This moderation system is not intended to account for any "rights" of a minority. " - Can you bring an example where the majority have direct rule over decisions related to science (in the real world)?

Majority in democracies is the wrong metaphor for the described conflicts. In democracy, minorities may suffer from lawmaking discriminating against them, and need protection by the constitution and supreme court.
In the case of this site that would be stack exchange the company, as this is what makes the "laws" for this site.
The closing of questions is more akin to Volunteer Police support. In general, the possible powers such helping civilian yield are limited to small-scale reversible actions. And over policing would typically be addressed by more training.
